# Shopify Products count

Tags: shopify

im currently face this problem where by tag count show current view count which is corrent.
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKQFS.jpg)
but when i click to individual tag, the number will add up together.
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NXpV.jpg)

```
{% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
   {% assign products_count = 0 %}
    {% for product in collection.products %}
        {% if product.tags contains tag %}
            {% assign products_count = products_count | plus: 1 %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% assign is_advanced_tag = false %}
    {% assign cat = tag | split: '_' | first %}
    {% unless cat == tag %}
      {% if cat_array contains cat %}
        {% assign is_advanced_tag = true %}
        {% if current_tags contains tag %}

          <li class="active-filter ">{{ tag | remove_first: cat | remove_first: '_' }}</li>
        {% else %}
          <li>{{ tag | remove_first: cat | remove_first: '_' | link_to_tag: tag }}</li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endunless %}

    {% if is_advanced_tag == false %}

      {% if current_tags contains tag %}


        <li class="active-filter ">

          {{ tag }}({{ collection.products_count }})
  </li>

      {% else %}

        <li>{{ tag | link_to_tag: tag }} ({{ collection.products_count }})</li>
      {% endif %}

    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

is there any where to show the non current view of product count. thanks

Comment: What is `cat_array` ? And what are you trying to do here: `{% assign cat = tag | split: '_' | first %}   {% unless cat == tag %}` ?

Comment: @HymnZ hi HymnZ, actually im not too sure myself, cause this code come with the theme i use in shopify. My guess for cat_array is category array which contain tag.